how to select Any of available fields with jq?
I'm trying to filter some journald logs which might have some-what similar information in different keys.
journalctl -o json | head -n 1000  | jq '.UNIT, .USER_UNIT, ._SYSTEMD_UNIT
Those 3 keys might have the unit name, depending on how the log entry was created (by the unit, by the system starting the unit, etc)... I don't care about this and just want to get the related-unit.
How can I extract something like jq '.UNIT OR .USER_UNIT OR ._SYSTEMD_UNIT (or doesn't work as it is a boolean converter to be used in select(), and | tries to route to a function)
I also cannot use + because when .UNIT key is present there will be something i don't want to collect in ._SYSTEMD_UNIT.

You can use the alternative operator //, which

produces all the values of its left-hand side that are neither false nor null, or, if the left-hand side produces no values other than false or null, then // produces all the values of its right-hand side

.UNIT // .USER_UNIT // ._SYSTEMD_UNIT

You can also add a constant fourth option as the last default, which is returned if all previous three fail. This can be anything, including the empty string "" for blank lines, or even empty to disregard these inputs entirely.

awesome. I did not see this on the manual :) ...And excellent suggestion on the last static value! cheers.

Another option is --output-field, but it has the side-effect that "_For the former, the "__CURSOR", "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP", "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP", and "BOOT_ID" fields are always printed."
journalctl --output-fields=UNIT,USER_UNIT,SYSTEMD_UNIT  -o json | 
    jq 'del(.__CURSOR, ._BOOT_ID, .__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP, .__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP)' | 
    grep -v '{}'

In the end the grep -v '{}' is needed to delete the empty results.

Good point. But I am trying to send logs from one place to another, there are many more fields I do need. I just need to "normalize" a couple of them before. It's one of those temporary-bash-things that will live on for 20yrs...
